# Check my contradiction proof

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

> Prove that $\forall n\in \Bbb N,(n>3\wedge n\mbox{ is prime})\to\exists q\in\Bbb N,(n=6q+1\lor n=6q+5)$.

Here's my attempted proof:

*Pf.* Suppose to the contrary that $\forall n\in \Bbb N,(n>3\wedge n\mbox{ is prime})\wedge \forall q\in\Bbb N,(n\ne 6q+1\wedge n\ne 6q+5)$. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (FTA), if $n$ is an integer, then $n$ is either a prime, or a product of unique primes $p_1p_2\dots p_{k-1}p_k$, $k\in \Bbb N$. We can say that, if $n$ is prime, $n$ can be represented as a sum of a product of unique primes $p_1p_2\dots p_{k-1}p_k$ and some integer remainder (since $p_1p_2\dots p_{k-1}p_k\nmid n$). However, when $n>3,n\ne 6q+1\implies n\ne(2)(3)q+1$ and $n\ne 6q+5\implies n\ne(2)(3)q+5$, which are contradictions to the FTA. Therefore, our original supposition must have been false, and $\forall n\in \Bbb N,(n>3\wedge n\mbox{ is prime})\to\exists q\in\Bbb N,(n=6q+1\lor n=6q+5)$. $\ \blacksquare$

The thing I'm shaky on is whether the contradiction I found is actually a contradiction ...

Comment: A much more straightforward argument:  Suppose that $n$ is neither representable as $6q+1$ nor as $6q+5$.  Then it must be representable as one of the following: $6q+0, 6q+2, 6q+3, 6q+4$ (*be sure to explain why: cite an appropriate theorem*).  Now, notice that $6q+2=2(3q+1)$ and $6q+3=3(2q+1)$ etc...  Explain why these observations are relevant and what they imply.

Comment: A counter-example is $n=5$. Here I am assuming $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3,...\}$.  But the JMoravitz way seems the best (assuming $n>5$).

Comment: Why would $n \ne 2*3q + 1$ or and $n\ne 6q + 5$ be a contradiction of FTA?  lots of numbers are neither of those.  $2,3,4,6,8,9,10,12,14,15,16,18$ etc.  are all not congruent to 1 or 5.  How does that violate FTA

Comment: "Here I am assuming N={1,2,3,...}"  That's not a valid assumption.  *many* texts allow $0 \in \mathbb N$ and that counter example is a trivial one.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument will yield a contradiction, but you haven't actually demonstrated it, yet. Also, your initial assumption is not what you should be making. Rather, you should assume the following: $$\exists n\in\Bbb N: (n\:\mathrm{is}\: \mathrm{prime})\wedge\bigl(\forall q\in\Bbb N,(n\neq 6q+1)\wedge(n\neq 6q+5)\bigr)$$

Comment: But I used arrow law, then I negated the whole statement. And how would I go about demonstrating that q is prime?

Comment: Not quite. The negation of "$\forall x, \Phi(x)$" is "$\exists x:\neg\Phi(x).$"

Comment: Also, you would *not* go about provong that $q$ is prime, because that isn't true for all $q\in\Bbb N.$ Rather, try to show that $n$ is *not* prime using the other two assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You claim to have contradicted the FTA, but I don't see that.  To contradict the FTA you would need two distinct factorizations of some number.

The first mistake you made was the negation of the proposition.  It should start with $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.  The rest of it is right, though:
$$
    \exists n\in\Bbb N: (n>3) \wedge (\text{$n$ is prime})\wedge\left(\forall q\in\Bbb N,(n\neq 6q+1)\wedge(n\neq 6q+5)\right)
$$
Proceed in cases: $n$ must be congruent to $0$, $2$, $3$, or $4$ modulo $6$.
In the cases $n\bmod 6 = 0$, $2$, or $4$, $n$ must be even.
In the case $n\bmod 6 = 3$ $n$ is a multiple of $3$.
In any case, $n$ has a positive divisor greater than $1$ and less than $n$, so can't be prime.  This contradicts the assumption that $n$ is prime.

Real proof by contradictions are when the contradiction is internal to the proof.  In this case, we ended up contradicting one of the hypotheses.  So this is really a proof by contrapositive.

Comment: Hmm .. I'm not understanding the modulo part ... where did you get those numbers 0, 2, 3, and 4?

Comment: There are 6 modulo class mod 6.  0, 1,2,3,4,5  If $n \not \equiv 1 \mod 6$ and $n \not \equiv 5 \mod 6$ then $n \equiv 0,2,3$ or $4 \mod 6$ (they are the only four left).  If $n \equiv 0, 2$ or $4 \mod 5$ then $2|n$.  If $n \equiv 3 \mod 5$ then $3|n$.